# Mysql Virtual IP and timeout

Tags: attack-prevention, apache, mysql, risk-analysis, vlans

What are the risk that I encounter when increasing the timeout of a vip between a web server (apache) and mysql cluster (two servers). Actually it is set to 5 minutes.

If time_out was 1hour,  knowing that all servers have a proxy to go out the vlan, could this be a security threat ?